# Tableview inside Flipview using Utility template

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

I'm new to iOS dev, so I do apologise for asking potentially dumb question.

What I want to do is something very similar to the default Weather app; where the app has a info button, it flips to another view which has a table along with a Done button to go back to the app.

I'm using the 'Utility Application' template which does most of this for me :)

However, I am now struggling to add a tableview into the flipview. Am I on the right path? I'm using storyboard at the moment - beginning to realise this is most likely a limitation on the GUI (after all a GUI can only go so far). If so, is this possible programatically and how would I go about applying it on a default 'Utility Application' template.

I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to drag and drop a UITableView onto your `flipsideViewController` in interface builder. Make sure that you like its delegate and data source to the view controller.

[image]

Then change `flipsideViewController.h` to create an instance variable for the array that will store the text for the cells labels and for the controller to conform to the tables delegate and data source methods.

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *myArrayOfItems;
}
```

In `flipsideViewController.m` alloc/init and populate your array in `viewDidLoad`

```
myArrayOfItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"firstItem",@"secondItem",@"thirdItem",@"fourthItem", nil];
```

And finally, copy and paste the following and you should have a working table!

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myArrayOfItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myArrayOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Selected cell index:%i",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: Wow what a thorough reply! Can't thank you enough! That worked perfectly - looks so simple too. :)